# Snowflake: How to insert into a table from a flattened array of date strings variable?

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, insert, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Brand new to Snowflake. I need to insert all the dates from an array into a date field in a table. I'm doing this through a JavaScript Stored Proc.

```
//get the array of dates
datesMissingArr = priorDatesArr.filter(date=>summDateArr.indexOf(date)==-1);
```

> `datesMissingArr` now equals this: `[  "2019-10-08",  "2019-09-08",  "2019-10-06" ]`

Now I want to take that and insert each one of those dates into a table, like so:

```
snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: `INSERT INTO "MYDB"."PUBLIC"."dates_table"("logdate") 
                             SELECT value::date FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(input => parse_json('${datesMissingArr}')));`                                         
                            } ).execute();
```

But I get an error:

> Error parsing JSON: garbage in the numeric literal: 2019-10-08,, pos 11 At Statement.execute

Some advice/help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the Array to a JSON string before calling `execute()`:
`var datesMissingStr = JSON.stringify(datesMissingArr);` and then use `${datesMissingStr}`.

But really you should *bind* the parameter:

```
snowflake.createStatement( { 
    sqlText: `INSERT INTO "dates_table"("logdate") 
              SELECT value::date FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(input => parse_json(:1)))`,
    binds:   [JSON.stringify(datesMissingArr)]
} ).execute();
```